# Document structure tags for accessibility breaks PDF saved from Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010

I have Word documents that needs to be saved as PDF. If I use Word 2010's "save as type: PDF" option, the PDF file created is broken (copy-paste duplicates selected text). If I disable "Include non-printing information - Document structure tags for accessibility", copy-paste works again.

Does anyone else have this problem? I have tried to clear extra information from the file by running "Inspect document", but that didn't help.

Alternatively, is there any way to disable "Document structure tags for accessibility" as default? (it is always selected when saving another document)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saving as PDF use the Save & Send pane to create a PDF file from the Word doc.

I'm honestly not sure what difference this makes technically, but if you save the Word doc as a PDF it doesn't encode properly. This method creates a more stable doc.

[image: The export to PDF function]

Comment: PDF file created by this method was still broken, I didn't see any difference

Comment: Very odd, it works fine for me in 2010.So to be clear; the issue you're having is that if you copy text in the PDF and paste it back into Word, it duplicates the text? Could you add a screen shot of the result to your question?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to change the font from Garamond to Calibri. However, this is not ideal since it changes the document layout.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible suggestions: Use the print function to send the document to a virtual printer that produces a PDF document instead. Otherwise try to save the document in DOC format first before saving to PDF using the same methods you have tried.